VirtualGL: How to select different device
I have a machine with AMD CPU (no integrated graphics) where I set up VirtualGL and I can use vglrun successfully to run programmes with hardware acceleration over a VNC connection.
Now, I want to set up the same on a different machine with Intel CPU (with integrated graphics). If I run glxspheres64 without vglrun, I see that llvmpipe is being used, as expected. However, if I run with vglrun, the machine uses the Intel integrated graphics instead of the GPU. How can I set VirtualGL up in a way such that it uses the GPU as hardware acceleration and not Intel integrated graphics?
EDIT: It is an NVIDIA GPU (RTX 2000 Ada Notebook)

Do you have a NVIDIA GPU? Please edit your question and provide a bit more information. I’ll just assume it’s NVIDIA for my answer- you can always substitute for your GPU instead.
You also have to ensure you have the latest VirtualGL installed.
Now, identify the GPU device number using the command vglinfo | grep "Device"
Create a configuration file (e.g., vgl_config) with the following content:
+iglxdev ~/dev/tty
+glxvendor NVIDIA
+glxdev <GPU_device_number>

Replace <GPU_device_number> with the actual number from step 2.
Run vglrun with the configuration file as an argument: vglrun -c vgl_config your_application
This should force VirtualGL to use the GPU for hardware acceleration instead of the Intel integrated graphics.
Be sure to make sure that the GPU driver is installed and configured properly. If you're using an NVIDIA GPU, ensure the NVIDIA driver is installed and configured to use the GPU.
Please comment if this doesn’t work- or any feedback in general :D
